# Getting the URL of the origin / referrer for user registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, referrer

I have a piece of code that I've tested for a simple user registration code:

```
   ReferrerURL = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
```

This property is set for user when he registers onto the website.

For example if user clicked onto the site via some ad, I'd like to get the origin site from where he came from.

With this piece of code I'm only getting the URL of my own site which looks like:

```
example.com/Registration
```

Regardless where the user came from... Is there any other way to fetch that information from where the user originally came (if it is available) - if not then just simply leave this field as null...

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoRegister(UserRegistrationViewModel model)
{
    var user = new Users()
    {
       FirstName = model.FirstName,
       LastName = model.LastName,
       Email = model.Email,
       CountryId = 230,
       Active = false,
       PasswordSalt = salt,
       PasswordHash = PasswordHelper.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, salt),
       GUID = _guid,
       HasSpecialSubscription = false,
       TotalScans = 0,
       IsFreeTrialExpired = false,
       DateOfRegistration = DateTime.Now,
       ReferrerId = referrerId,
       AffiliatePct = 0.15,
       Cycles = 3,
       ReferrerURL = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
    };
}
```

Comment: I've undone the close vote, you may want to remove those comments

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be getting the Referrer when the user GETs the Register page, the POST should be from your own site, always.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto could you please clarify it to me a little bit more? To make the action as GET or ? Should I be getting the URL referrer from origin site via Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri property?

Comment: @User987, while you making your post request from view then just set your `ReferrerURL` to `document.referrer;` and then send it to controller's method. you will get original referrer

Comment: I'm assuming your ad leads to a registration page in your website (as it should). If that's correct, you should get the referrer when you load the registration page, either from c# as you are doing or as @ershoaib mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A referrer is a header sent by browsers when the user navigates to another page, so the target site knows the originating site - if a browser is configured to send it (privacy settings or plugins may strip the header) and if the sites use the same scheme (referrers aren't sent when transferring from http to https or vice versa).

But every click resets the referrer to the current page. So if your users flow like this:

```
External Site -> Registration Page -> Registration POST Handler
```

Then in the last one, the referrer will be your registration page, not the external site's address.

So you need to save the referrer in the registration page, and forward it to your POST action. You could do so in a hidden form field, or by storing it in the session, or in a cookie. All approaches have their pros and cons.